# Iron Router parameter returns no results

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I'm trying to use a parameter in Iron Router. My url is `/activity/dJW9PWJEmSqT3bbSA`.

Here's what I have so far:

```
Router.route('/activity/:_id', function() {
  var params = this.params;
  console.log(params);
  var activityID = params._id;
  var currentActivity = Activities.findOne({_id: this.activityID});
  this.layout('fullScreen', {
    data: {
      activity: currentActivity,
      activityStarted: false
    }
  });
  this.render('activityDetail');
});
```

`console.log(params)` returns `[] (0)`. I'm not sure why.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Router.route('/activity/:_id', function() {
    this.render('activityDetail',{
        data: function(){
            return Activities.findOne({_id: this.params._id})
        }
    });
});
```